# Better way for this layout with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I try to do this layout with CSS only (no JS, etc.), within an existing html page (do NOT change the HTML code). But couldn’t get all the positions I need. See if anyone has a better idea. Thanks in advance.

The existing HTML is like (class name is used to illustrate it):

```
<body-wrapper>

<logo>
</logo>

<nav>
</nav>

<content>
</content>

<footer>
</footer>

</body-wrapper>
```

The layout I want is like:

```
|--------------------|
| logo |             |
|------|             |
| Nav  |             |
|      |  content    |
|      |             |
|      |             |
|------|-------------|
|        footer      |
|--------------------|
```

Or this:

```
|--------------------|
| logo |             |
|------|             |
| Nav  |             |
|      |  content    |
|      |             |
|      |             |
|      |-------------|
|      |  footer     |
|--------------------|
```

Note: I wish NOT to change the HTML layout (don't add another div to wrap the log and nav bar, etc.), and only change the CSS to get the desired layout. Also, I don't know the height of these components.

The way I tried is to set the width for Logo and Nav, and use absolute (top = 0, right = 0) for the content. However, the footer will jump up to just below the Nav and overlap with the content. :-(

Any idea to get the desired layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` with `order:#` ?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n3frons4/3/

It should be the easiest way to create responsive website.

Comment: Thanks. I think this works, though looks like its needs IE 11 or above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some illustrations from Codrops http://tympanus.net/codrops/ or Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="left">
    <header class="logo">logo</header>
    <nav class="nav">Nav</nav>
</div>
<div class="main-content">content</div>
<footer class="footer">footer</footer>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
width:100%;
max-width:800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.left {
width:30%;
float:left;
}
.logo {
width:100%;
height: 50px;
background:blue;
}
.nav {
width:100%;
height: 100px;
background: pink;
}
.main-content {
width:70%;
height:auto;
float:right;
}
.footer {
clear:both;
width:100%;
padding: 1em 0;
background:red;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddel link to visaulize it https://jsfiddle.net/wrLzv4cx/.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">

.body-wrapper{
width:800px;
height:400px;
border:#000 2px dashed;
}

.div_left{
height:400px;
width:200px;
border-right:#000 2px dashed;
float:left;
}

.logo{
width:200px;
height:100px;
border-bottom:#000 2px dashed;
}
.nav{
width:200px;
height:300px;
}

.div_right{
width:590px;
height:400px; 
float:right;
}
.content{
width:590px;
height:300px;
border-bottom:#000 2px dashed;

}
.footer{
width:590px;
height:100px;

}


</style>


</head>

<body>

<div class="body-wrapper">

    <div class="div_left">

        <div class="logo">
            logo
        </div>

        <div class="nav">
            nav
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div_right">
        <div class="content">
            content
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>

   </body>
    </html>
```

output ->
[image]

Comment: Thank you -- I guess I forgot to mention that I wish not to change the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples that can give you something to work off of depending on if the img/nav need to be stationary or not. It's simply accounting for the relationship between each elements position. Fairly self explanatory it you take the time to break apart the CSS.

**Example 1**: Fixed Nav

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #266080;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.logo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background: #2EA1C7;
}
.content {
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #024D66;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/024D66/fff">
</div>
<nav class="nav"></nav>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with dypesetting,
    remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsext of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsext of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
    remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
    not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

**Example 2**: Non-fixed Nav

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #266080;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background: #2EA1C7;
}
.content {
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #024D66;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/024D66/fff">
</div>
<nav class="nav"></nav>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with dypesetting,
    remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsext of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsext of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
    has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
    remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
    not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think both solution need to know the height of logo, which I don't have, so it doesn't work for my case. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;    
}
.wrapper .col{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.wrapper .col-1{
    width: 200px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.wrapper .col-2{    
    background: #ccc;
}

.logo{
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
nav,
section{
    min-height: 250px;
    padding: 15px;    
}
footer{
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #999;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col col-1">
        <aside>
            <a href="/" class="logo">LOGO</a>
            <nav>nav</nav>
        </aside>    
    </div>
    <div class="col col-2">
        <section>content</section>
        <footer>footer</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/au1b82h3/)